# Problem with deriving the cumulative distribution from the density function

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function

Consider the continuous distribution with density function
$$
p(x) = \frac{1}{2}\cos(x) \;, \quad -\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{\pi}{2}.
$$

I want to derive the cumulative distribution function for this density function. In other examples I've seen, this is usually done by taking the anti-derivate of the density function which (in the examples that I've seen) leads to a valid CDF.

However, it seems that following the same approach for this example yields an invalid CDF,
$$
\begin{cases}
\: -0.5 , \quad \quad x \leq \frac{-\pi}{2}  \\
\frac{1}{2}\sin(x), \: \: -\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{\pi}{2} \\
\: \: \: 0.5, \quad \quad x \geq \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{cases}
$$
and that it somehow needs rescaling. What am I doing wrong here, and how does one go about finding the CDF for this density function?

[image]

Comment: The integral for the CDF of a density $f$ is, generically, $F(x) =\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,\mathrm dt.$ Notice the lower limit.  You started with a lower limit of $0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about the constant of integration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_integration

Just add $C = 0.5$ and your anti derivative becomes a valid CDF with corresponding density $p(x)$.